# Is there a function to copy one sheet to another but in a different layout?

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have 70+ sheets of data. Each sheet is for just one location on a certain date. There are several time recordings for each date with values for pH, temperature etc (see 'input'). How do I get it into the form ('output') without copying and pasting over and over again? I basically need the 'input' data in a form that can be used for a pivot chart.

Input:
[image]

Output:
[image]

I've attempted using the `indirect` function with `match/index` to sort of reference the worksheet but I'm not smart enough to figure it out. Also, looked at 'relationships' but that's not worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look into powerquery.

Comment: giving that a go now, tried it yesterday and wasn't having success but will give it another go today, thanks

Comment: Yes as mentioned above by @Ike ma'am you need `Power Query` it will be easy more here